# GCP Console is empty but I can access everything through CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I cannot access anything through Console even when I have the required permissions. I have to use a cloud shell command. For example, if I want to see my buckets, here is what the console shows me:
[Empty Cloud Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e5L7.png)

But When I try to access it through CLI, it shows me all the buckets there are.
[Buckets List through CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILGOs.png)

The same thing is happening with any other service, like Bigquery etc. I cannot see anything on Console.
I've tried clearing all cookies and logging in again, it did not work.
Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Check which IAM roles are assigned to the identity you are using. Most likely you do not have permission to view resources.

Comment: you can also see the list of [IAM permissions reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference)

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley  for this. Actually me and my colleague have the same permissions but he can view the resources and I cannot. that's what is confusing me